# Creating nested model from II level structure model

Tags: c#, .net-core, model

Good day, I have this class with nested model:

```
public class EmailMessage
{

    public class EmailAddress
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }

    public EmailMessage()
    {
        ToAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
        FromAddresses = new List<EmailAddress>();
    }

    public List<EmailAddress> ToAddresses { get; set; }
    public List<EmailAddress> FromAddresses { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

---

When implementing ***Forgot Password*** there is an issue with create that type of model, but I have problem with syntax - i trying in this way:

```
        var message = new EmailMessage
        {
            ToAddresses =
            {
                Name = "Test",
                Address = "test@gmail.com",
            },
            Subject = "Reset password token",
            Content = callback);
        }
```

How is the proper syntax? There is need for use foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `List<EmailAddress>` with a `new` operator, and then initialize each new `EmailAddress` in the list with a `new` operator as well. Furthermore, you defined a constructor, which requires both `ToAddresses` and `FromAddresses` lists. You can instantiate it like this:

```cs
var message = new EmailMessage(
  ToAddresses: new List<EmailAddress>() 
  { 
     new EmailAddress()
     {
         Name = "Test", 
         Address = "test@gmail.com"
     }
  }, 
  FromAddresses: new List<EmailAddress>())
{
  Subject = "Reset password token", 
  Content = callback
};
```

Note, just like in your code in the question, currently the `FromAddreeses` list is empty.

If you have multiple addresses coming from another collection, such as a database for instance, you can use a `foreach` to build the `List<EmailAddress>` as well, and then just pass that built list in place of the `new List...`  in the example above. Note that `foreach` cannot be used inside the initialization syntax - it has to be a separate statement to build the lists.

Comment: Thanks - it's exactly, which i search. FromAddresses is empty - cause it's the same like ToAddresses.

Ok - so if there will be more emails then foreach for build List<EmailAddress> will be helpfull.